# Create an instance of an object C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor, abstract-class

I have recently picked up C++ but I am having problems in some areas as I am used to Java and I am not sure if I am going about things the right way.

I have a text file which lines are structured like this

```
C;101;1;1;4;10;
H;102;9;0;1;8;2
C;103;9;9;2;5;
C;104;0;9;3;8;
```

; being the delimeter

C is used to check if its a Crawler(H is used to check if it is a Hopper), it is then followed by the id, positions, directions(1-4), size, and alive(0/1)

I have an abstract Bug class then I have a Crawler and Hopper class which both inherit from the Bug class.

Here is my Bug class

```
class Bug
{
public:
    int id;
    pair<int, int> position;
    int direction;
    int size;
    bool alive;
    list<pair<int, int>> path;
    virtual void move() {}
    bool isWayBlocked() {}


    Bug(string type, int id, pair <int, int> position, int direction, int size, bool alive)
    {
        type = type;
        id = id;
        position = position;
        direction = direction;
        size = size;
        alive = alive;
    };
};
```

Here is the Crawler class

```
class Crawler : public Bug
{
public:
    Crawler(int id, pair <int, int> position, int direction, int size)
        : Bug("Crawler", id, position, direction, size, alive)
    {
    }



};
```

Here is an example of me trying to create an instance of a Crawler object:

```
Bug* bugPtr;
        if (bugType == "C") {
            bugPtr = new Crawler(bugID, { xPos,yPos }, direction, size);
            //Crawler* CrawlerBugPointer = new Crawler(bugID, { xPos,yPos }, direction, size);
        }
```

I am able to easily read from the text file and store the variables but when i start debugging all of the fields in the bugPtr say 0, I suspect that I have gone about things in completely the wrong way and have not built the Abstract class and Inheritor classes properly, could anyone point out what I am doing wrong? any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `type = type;` = You need to learn about variable shadowing and [constructor lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler should have generated a warning, "Expression with possibly no effect" (or similar), for every line in your constructor. Read the warnings - they're useful.

```
Bug(string type, int id, pair <int, int> position, int direction, int size, bool alive)
    {
        this->type = type;
        this->id = id;
        this->position = position;
        this->direction = direction;
        this->size = size;
        this->alive = alive;
    };
```

While C++ doesn't require the ridiculous use of `this` everywhere, in your case it's necessary since you've given the constructor parameters the same names as the fields. When you enter something like

```
id = id;
```

You're saying, "Find the variable with name `id` in this scope, and assign its value to itself." Which does nothing, which is why all of your fields were left at their default values. Saying `this.id` means, "Find the class field with name `id` and assign the value of the local `id` to it."

Comment: Thanks very much, I had this.id before but that gave errors, I use this.id all the time in Java but never actually knew what it meant thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Gabriel No worries, glad it helped. You'll find that while C++ looks *mostly* like Java in many cases, they're very different languages. Expertise in one doesn't easily translate to the other. If you're planning on storing these bugs in an array or a vector, go look up "c++ object slicing."

Comment: Last I knew. `type` was not a reserved word in C++. And this initialization really should be done with an initializer list.

Comment: @PeteBecker I removed the `type` comment. I felt that modifying the OP's constructor was a more clear explanation, since they're just getting started with the language. There's no perf benefit to an intiializer list; it's just convenience.

Comment: There is a performance benefit when types have non-trivial default constructors. And, of course, if a type has no default constructor it must be initialized in the initializer list. Not to mention that an initializer list deals with those duplicate names appropriately. Beginners should always use initializer lists.

Comment: @PeteBecker none of those comments apply in this case. Beginners should understand what the initializer list *does*, not just use it (or any other syntactic sugar feature) blindly.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is with an initializer list:

```
Bug(string type, int id, pair <int, int> position, int direction, int size, bool alive)
: type(type), id(id), position(position), direction(direction), size(size), alive(alive)
{ }
```

The problem with the original code is name hiding. In the constructor body, `type = type` simply assigns the value of the argument named `type` to the argument named `type`. It doesn’t change the value of the member named `type`.

But in an initializer list, in an entry like `type(type)`, the first `type` is the name of the member and the second `type` is the name of the argument. So the member gets the argument value, and all is well.

You should **always** use initializer lists in constructors. In addition to allowing duplicate names (if that’s what you like; many programmers don’t) they are more efficient when you have data members with more complex initialization.